# Android program to interact with Square Reader

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, nfc, square

I have a Square Reader which supports reading NFC cards. I also have an NFC card which can store and send data. Is is possible for me to write an Android program using Android Studio to start the communication between the Android Virtual Device(AVD) and my Square Reader when I tap my card on the reader? I have an USB cable that can be used to connect the reader to my laptop. The Square Reader can also connect to the laptop by means of Bluetooth.

PS: I am from India and I have found that the API for the Square Reader is available only in US and Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use the Square reader as a generic NFC card reader, which wouldn't be possible. You will likely have better luck using a physical android device to do the NFC reading, or buying a different NFC reader.

You are correct about the API country availability https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq-international-availability/